# quill-html-edit-button Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, quill

I have nuxt project where i use "Quill editor", and I'm trying to add quill-html-edit-button like in example https://github.com/benwinding/quill-html-edit-button, but after rebuilding my app i've got "Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined". Can someone help me, please? 
My code:

"quillEditor.js" imported like plugin in "nuxt.config"

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueQuillEditor from 'vue-quill-editor';
import Quill from 'quill'
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-vue'
import VideoResize from 'quill-video-resize-module';
import {ImageUpload} from 'quill-image-upload';

import htmlEditButton from "quill-html-edit-button";

Quill.register('modules/ImageResize', ImageResize);
Quill.register('modules/VideoResize', VideoResize);
Quill.register('modules/imageUpload', ImageUpload);
Quill.register('modules/htmlEditButton', htmlEditButton);

Vue.use(VueQuillEditor);
```

component

```
<quill-editor
                    ref="editor"
                    :content="formInitialData.content"
                    :options="editorOption"
                  />

editorOption: {
      theme: 'snow',
      modules: {
        toolbar: [
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
          ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
          [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],
          [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
          [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],
          [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
          [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],
          [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
          [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
          [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
          [{ 'font': [] }],
          [{ 'align': [] }],
          ['clean'],
          ['link', 'image', 'video']
        ],
        ImageResize: {},
        VideoResize: {},
        htmlEditButton: {
          debug: true,
          msg: "Edit the content in HTML format",
          okText: "Ok",
          cancelText: "Cancel",
          buttonHTML: "HTML",
          buttonTitle: "Show HTML source",
          syntax: false,
          prependSelector: 'div#myelement',
          editorModules: {}
        },
        imageUpload: {
          url: process.env.apiUrl + '/push-s3',
          method: 'POST',
          name: 'file',
          withCredentials: false,
          headers: {},
          csrf: { token: 'token', hash: '' },
          callbackOK: (serverResponse, next) => {
            if(serverResponse.success){
              next(serverResponse.data);
            }
          },
          callbackKO: serverError => {
            console.log(serverError);
          },
          checkBeforeSend: (file, next) => {
            console.log(this.apiUrl);
            next(file);
          }
        },
      },
      placeholder: 'Insert text here ...',
    },
```

packege.json

```
 "quill-html-edit-button": "^2.2.7",
```